# ¿Cómo generar un .exe?

Tags: python, pyqt5, interfaz-gráfica, spyder

He buscado por Internet y no logro encontrar una forma de generar un archivo `.exe` de mi archivo `GUI.py`.

El caso es que en mi archivo `GUI.py` uso las librerías de `PyQt5` y además cargo los archivos `.ui` que creé con `Qt Designer` para hacer una mejor GUI.

Quisiera saber si realmente se puede generar un `.exe` conservando el formato que usé en los `.ui` y de ser así, cómo lo hago.

Comment: En lugar de mantener los .ui, transformalos a .py mediante `pyside2uic` y pyinstaller no te dará problemas. (pyside2uic porque yo utilizo PySide2, la librería oficial de QT. Imagino que habrá un equivalente de ese comando en PyQt, aunque no sea oficial.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar con pyinstaller

primero instalarlo con

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

## Archivo sin interfase

```
pyinstaller --onefile #el nombre de tu archivo .py
```

## Si tu archivo tiene interfase

```
pyinstaller --windowed --onefile #y aqui el nombre de tu archivo .py
```

## Ejemplo

```
pyinstaller --windowed --onefile GUI.py
```

Cuando te crea el archivo y lo ejecutas.

Te debería de abrir una consola y posteriormente tu programa
Si quisieras que no apareciera esta pantalla

tienes que colocar tu archivo como .pyw

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de hacerlo, yo lo hice con AutoPyToExe, lo instalas con

```
pip install Auto-Py-To-Exe
```

Y lo abres escribiendo `Auto-Py-To-Exe`

Se abrirá una interfaz en la cual te será muy sencillo hacerlo, yo acabo
de hacer ejecutable un archivo .ui también, en Additional Files carga tu
archivo .py el .ui y la bd y las respectivas imagenes/iconos
(Las imagenes e iconos deben de estar en la direccion del main.py y en pyqt5
el path de las imagenes también deben de estar en la direccion del main.py, sino al momento de hacer el .exe no saldrán las imagenes).
**Yo tuve problemas al ponerlo en OneFile, prueba con ambas por si acaso**